Attomic Vector Error when calling nl@simdesign_lhs using nlrx package
I am attempting to use the nlrx package in R with hopes of integrating optimization to my netlogo model.
I have written the following code to test a simple run, however when executing the following line nl@simdesign <- simdesign_lhs(nl=nl), I get an error : Error in x$min : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. I am unable to figure out whats causing and wondering if anyone has any idea. The code is listed below and if it helps the netlogo model is here, https://github.com/imantha-das/CRTT
library(nlrx)

root_d <- file.path("/home/imantha/workspace/CRTT")
netlogo_p <- file.path("/home/imantha/tools/NetLogo-6.4.0-64")
model_p <- file.path(root_d, "model","crtt_v2.nlogo")

# Create directory to store results
dir.create(file.path(root_d, "results"), showWarnings = FALSE)

out_p <- file.path(root_d, "results")

nl <- nl(nlversion = "6.4.0", nlpath = netlogo_p, modelpath = model_p, jvmmem = 1024)

# Attach an Experiment
nl@experiment <- experiment(
  expname = "crtt-test",
  outpath = out_p,
  repetition = 1,
  tickmetrics = "true",
  idsetup = "Setup",
  idgo = "Go",
  runtime = 7201,
  evalticks = seq(180,7200,60),
  metrics = c(
    "count cas-agents with [pma-name = 'Vieux Habitants PMA' and in-queue? = True and deceased? = False]"
  ),
  variables = list(
    "heli-rescue?" = FALSE,
    "Speed-Helicopter" = 200, 
    "no-heli-agent" = 3,
    "heli-agent-cap" = 2,
    
    "no-resc-agent-A" = 20,
    "no-resc-agent-B" = 15,
    "resc-agent-cap" = 3,
    "resc-agent-A-only" = TRUE,
    "Rescue-Time-Mins" = 10,
    "Transfer-Time-Mins" = 5,
    "Speed" = 30,
    "increase-rescue-agents-at-time" = 60,
    "Increase-Rescue-Agents" = 2,
    "transfer-hosp-vh" = 10,
    "transfer-hosp-sm" = 8,
    "pma-cap-t1" = 5,
    "pma-cap-t2" = 30,
    "pma-operational-t1" = 180,
    "pma-operational-t2" = 300,
    "stabilisation-t" = 17,
    "no-bb" = 6,
    "no-nbb" = 212
  ),
  constants = list()
)

nl@simdesign <- simdesign_lhs(nl=nl)

>>> Error in x$min : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors


simdesign_lhs uses the Latin Hypercube Sampling Method. This is used to test a range of values for the given variables. For each variable one has to define this range as a list. For instance
variables = list("initial-number-sheep" = list(min=50, max=150, step=10, qfun="qunif"),
                 "initial-number-wolves" = list(min=50, max=150, step=10, qfun="qunif"))

Have a look at the LHS example of the nlrx documentation. You will also find a section about Model Optimization there.
